# Carry POST through html hyperlink

Tags: php, html

I have a hyperlink as shown:

```
<div style="clear:both"> <a color="grey" accesskey=""style="float: right" href="newbattle.php? userid= <?php echo $id0; ?>"> [<font color="grey">Attack</font>]</a><br></div>  <br>
```

Is it possible, using only only php, to carry POST data? I want to put this

```
<input type="hidden" name="test" value="<?php  echo $number;?>
```

So I can `$_POST['test']` on the other page and get the `$number`. I can switch over to normal form but I really like what I have

Comment: No you can't access `$_POST` variables through a hyperlink.

Comment: @Daan Would explain why I couldn't find anything about it, thanks!

Comment: is the link on the page after you have posted?

Comment: You can do this using JavaScript. Will it suit your problem?

Comment: @AdilAliyev It will not solve my problem but it may help others who find this question so thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible. If you want to submit a POST request, you should go through a `<form>` and submit it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot post through a hyperlink, unless you use JavaScript to capture the click event and simulate a click on a submit button.

But a better approach, I think, would be to make an actual submit button. With a bit of CSS you can style that button to look as if it was a hyperlink. That way, if the CSS fails, you've still got a working button, while if a JavaScript issue would occur, you have a disfunctional link with unexpected behaviour.

```css
input[type=submit] {
  display: inline;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<form action="otherpage.php" method="POST">
   <input type="hidden" name="test" value="<?php  echo $number;?>">
   <input type="submit" value = "Look, I'm a link!">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

A link redirects user to another page, it's purpose is not for get/post requests.

If you want to send a post request on a click, you can do it with a submit button inside form. For example,

```
<form action="another_page.php" method="POST">
   <input type="hidden" name="test" value="<?php  echo $number;?>
   <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Style the button like a hyperlink and it will send a post request as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using a form.

When the user clicks the link, the form is submitted with the "test" variable and the "userid" variable.

Here's the code:

```
<form method="post" action="newbattle.php" id="myForm">
    <div style="clear:both">
        <a color="grey" accesskey="" style="float:right;" href="" onclick="javascript:document.myForm.submit(); return false;">[<font color="grey">Attack</font>]</a>
        <br/>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <input type="hidden" name="userid" value="<?php echo $id0; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="test" value="<?php echo $number; ?>" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

For my specific problem, here's what I ended up doing.

```
href="newbattle.php?userid= <?php echo $id0; ?>&num=<?php echo $number; ?>"
```

I added the `$number` on to the hyperlink and then retrieved it with `$_GET` on the next page

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access `test` value by `$_POST` you have to use form like this :

```
<form action="another_page.php" method="POST">
   <input type="hidden" name="test" value="<?php  echo $number;?>
   <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**get.php :**

```
<?php

$num = $_POST['test'];

echo $num;

?>
```